# Считывание из текстового файла последние 10 строк

Tags: java

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как считать из текстового файла последние 10 строк?

Comment: использую IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 (версия коммьюнити). Мне хватает, т.к. пишу только плагины к Neo4j

Comment: уже несколько файлов с той страницы подгрузил как вы сказали, не получается все равно! добавляю запись import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader
ругается на слово org

Comment: А загуглить Apache Commons IO никак? Держите [ссылку][1] на даунлоад.

  [1]: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: falstaf,скачал по ссылке все что мог, добавил как посоветовал vinger4, Netbeans: Tools > Options > Java > ADD JAR/ZIP
все также тут import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader ругается на слово org

Comment: Извините, я ошибался. Джарник подключается для каждого проекта отдельно: на вкладке Projects на текущем проекте кликайте правой кнопкой, выбираете в контекстном меню "Properties", далее ищете вкладку Libraries - туда надо подключить джарник.

Comment: ещё главный клаас попросил добавить " throws Exception":
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

Comment: теперь тут import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader;
ругается на слово ReversedLinesFileReader

Comment: Может быть вам стоит всё же сесть и освоить азы, а не спрашивать каждый свой шаг? Это займёт времени не больше, чем писать сюда и ждать ответа.

Comment: Подключение и использование библиотек — есть ни что иное, как азы. Почитайте про это, а заодно изучите ant/maven, хотя бы на начальном уровне — сильно упростит жизнь.

Comment: > Пока некогда читать!

Мда. Удачи вам с таким подходом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    File file = new File("/home/vinger4/water_calc");
    ReversedLinesFileReader in = new ReversedLinesFileReader(file);
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Подправил.

Если без апаче, то можно просто считать файл, а затем реверснуть лист:

```
        FileReader file = new FileReader("/home/vinger4/water_calc");
        CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(10000);
        file.read(buf);
        file.close();
        String current_string = "";
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (char ch: buf.array())
        {
            current_string += ch;
            if (ch == '\n')
            {
                strings.add(current_string);
                current_string = "";
            }
        }
        Collections.reverse(strings);
        System.out.println(strings);
```

Подключить можно просто джарник как я понимаю в Netbeans: Tools > Options > Java > ADD JAR

http://apache-mirror.rbc.ru/pub/apache//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.4-bin.zip

Comment: Не пойму, почему то ругается на слово ReversedLinesFileReader

Comment: Может быть класс надо импортировать?

Comment: да, забыл упомянуть что он из апаче: import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader

Comment: у меня ругается на слово org, вы апаче отдельно подключали?

Comment: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache.commons локально скачал отсюда джарник

при сборке прописано:

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: А без апаче никак по другому?

Comment: vinger4, а вы в какой среде программируете?